# how to refer elastic search JavaScript client library in node js controller files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, elasticsearch

I am doing node.js **RESTapi** in express framework. I want to integrate elastic search to my project. So I installed elastic search JavaScript client library and add these codes in `app.js`.

```
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'localhost:9200',
    log: 'trace'
});

client.ping({
    requestTimeout: 30000,
}, function (error) {
    if (error) {
        console.error('elasticsearch cluster is down!');
    } else {
        console.log('All is well');
    }
});
```

and I am getting '**All is well**'.
But how do I refer this client in my controller files.

Comment: What do you mean, you don't know how to access `client` var from another file?

Comment: `require('../<controller>')(client)`

Comment: @ŞivāSankĂr client variable is in the app.js file. I want to refer this in categorry.controller.js file. So require('../app.js')(client) is this correct?

Comment: @deathangel908 yes I don't know how to call this client from another file.

Comment: In `app.js` use `require(categorry.controller.js)(client)` to send client variable to `categorry.controller.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Passing Arguments :**

Pass your variable as arguments to your import function, Like this you can pass variable from one file to another file.

```
//app.js
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'localhost:9200',
    log: 'trace'
});
var catRouters = require("categorry.controller.js")(client);

// categorry.controller.js
module.exports = function (client) {
    ....
    return { create, read, update, readById, categoriesByCity, live_search };
};
```

**Using Global Variables :**

Set your variable into Node.js global object to use in other files, Node.js global objects are global in nature and available in all modules.

```
//app.js
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'localhost:9200',
    log: 'trace'
});
global.client = client;

// categorry.controller.js
....
consoel.log(global.client);
```

Comment: In my category.controller.js file I already have module.exports = {
    create,
    read,
    update,
    readById,
    categoriesByCity,
    live_search
} .I am getting this error TypeError: require(...) is not a function. I want to client inside create function

Comment: Thanks but now I am facing an issue in controller.routes.js file. router.post('/', controller.create) Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]

Comment: I hope now I fixed the importing client variable part. But is there a way to solve this new issue?

Comment: Your file link in the way that `app.js -> controller.routes.js -> categorry.controller.js` ?

Comment: Exactly what I export from is refer in routes then export routes to app.js

Comment: do the same thing for `router`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187914/discussion-between-pathum-samararathna-and-siv-sankr).